# Cannot read property 'runnable' of null in Jest test

Tags: angular, typescript, selenium-webdriver, jestjs

I created new .spec file and tests inside it are falling with the following error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'runnable' of null

      at ret (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:175:25)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:26)
      at ProxyZoneSpec.Object.<anonymous>.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:39)
      at ZoneDelegate.Object.<anonymous>.ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:32)
      at Zone.Object.<anonymous>.Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:138:43)
      at Object.testBody.length.done (node_modules/jest-zone-patch/index.js:51:29)
```

I haven't see this one before, Google also didn't hear of it yet. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

While preparing minimal reproduction code to answer this question I noticed one suspicious import:

```
import { beforeEach } from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';
```

Which has been added by my IDE and caused the issue. Removing it is all you need to do :)